# Суффиксы -ИК- и -НИК- в существительных

Tags: орфография, словообразование, суффиксы, нн

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в таком вопросе.

В именах существительных есть два суффикса: -ИК- и -НИК-. Как понять, в каком случае употребляется один и в каком — другой?
Я прочла информация о том, что суффикс -НИК- добавляется к словам, обозначающим профессию и род деятельности (например, слово лесник). А как же тогда объяснить слова **медик** и **механик**, в которых суффикс -ИК-? Это разве не род деятельности?

Хочу понять написание Н и НН, связанное с этими суффиксами. Не могу объяснить это ребёнку. Я знаю, что если в основе слова, от которого образовано такое же существительное, есть буква Н, то будет писать НН, если нет, то одна. Как тогда быть со словом механик, например? Если бы в нём был суффик -НИК-, то писалось бы две буквы Н. Но пишется одна. Почему тогда суффикс -ИК-, а не -НИК-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Выбор Н/НН в существительных определяется при анализе **словообразования**, поэтому желательно работать со словарями (толковый на Грамоте.ру и словообразовательный).

Суффикс ***НИК*** (вариант суффикса ***ИК***) может обозначать **лицо,** в том числе по отношению к роду деятельности или **предмет** по отношению к другому предмету. Фактически это составной суффикс ***Н + ИК***.

2. **Какое здесь правило**? Попробуем его вывести сами. Рассмотрим слово ***пленник***, две буквы НН.

***Пленник***, м. 1. Тот, кто взят в плен, находится в плену; пленный.

Итак, слово можно образовать от существительного «плен» и формы прилагательного «пленный»: плен –  плен/ник или  пленн/ый – пленн/ик.

И формулируем правило: при образовании **существительного от существительного** используется суффикс ***НИК***, а суффикс ***ИК*** используется при образовании **существительного от прилагательного**. При этом учитывается наличие Н/НН в исходной основе.

3. **Проверяем слова:**

***Лесник***, м. Лесной сторож; работник лесного хозяйства. Лесн/ой – лесн/ик, (или лес – лес/ник)

***Сонник***, м. Старинная книга с толкованиями снов. Сон – сон/ник (или сонн/ый – сонн/ик)

***Малинник***, м. Заросли малины. Малина – малин/ник.

***Дворник***, м. 1. Работник, обязанный охранять дом, поддерживать чистоту и порядок **во дворе** и на улице перед домом. Двор – двор/ник.

Также: сторона – сторон/ник, измена – измен/ник.

4. Слово «медик» образуется **особым способом**: медицина – мед/ик, усечение основы + суффикс ИК или усечение основы и чередование Ц/К

Механик, механика (от греч. méchanikē) – в этих словах элемент ИК входит в основу и словообразовательным элементом не является.

Comment: Вы, Sharon, отличный учебник несколькотомный могли бы написать! Доступный для понимания обывателя!!! Желаю Вам написать такой учебник! Объясняете прекрасно! Педагогический талант!
Данное сообщение ответа не требует :)

Comment: Спасибо за вашу оценку!

Comment: От "механический" образовано "механика" и "механик"? Откуда вы взяли такой бред. Слово "механ-ич-еск-ий" образовано от механ-ик-а (суффиксальный способ). И слово "механ-ик" образовано от него же (способ тот же - нулевая суффиксация, как и в случае со словом "медик".

Comment: Первое же значение слова "механический" в РАН: "1. Относящийся к процессам и явлениям, изучаемым механикой" - откуда вы взяли, что механический стоит раньше механики?

Comment: Я поправила ответ по вашему замечанию. Если вы замечаете неточность, то надо вежливо сказать о этом. Здесь не рекомендуется использовать грубые просторечия. Это сайт вопросов и ответов по грамотному русскому языку, а не разговорный чат. Вопрос был о суффиксах ИК/НИК, и я объясняла правописание.  Это слово не подходило под общее правило, и именно это было важно, а не словообразовательный анализ.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Очень помогли!